# Thread Pooling for a method which has a return type

Tags: c#

I have a method named `InitializeCRMService()` which returns an object of `IOrganizationService`. Now I am defining a different method named `GetConnection(string thread)` which calls `InitializeCRMService()` based on the parameter passed to it. If the string passed to `GetConnection` is single it will start a single threaded instance of the `IntializeCRMService()` method, but if the string passed is multiple, I need to use a thread pool where I need to pass the method to `QueueUserWorkItem`. The method `InitializeCRMService` has no input parameters. It just returns a service object. Please find below the code block in the `GetConnection` method:

```
public void GetConnection(string thread)
{
    ParallelOptions ops = new ParallelOptions();

    if(thread.Equals("one"))
    {
        Parallel.For(0, 1, i =>
        {
            dynamic serviceObject = InitializeCRMService();       
        });
    }
    else if (thread.Equals("multi"))
    {
        // HERE I NEED TO IMPLEMENT MULTITHREADING USING THREAD POOL 
        // AND NOT PARALLEL FOR LOOP......
        // ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback(InitializeCRMService));
    }
}
```

Please note my method `InitializeCRMService()` has a return type of Service Object.

Please tell me how do I implement it.

Comment: I've decided to check in what thread the code ends up executing, and I have this to report: when using Parallel.For it sometimes uses the same thread, and sometimes not [Of course if you wanted to run it on the same thread, you would just call it]. On the other hand, when using the ThreadPool as in my answer it always runs on a background thread (from the thread pool evidently).

Comment: Yes @Thearot..that is what i wanted.But can you put some highlight as to how to go forward with the _service object returned by the InitializeCRMService method? You said I need to use a Manual Reset Event and also take care of thread affinity in the store method.

Comment: I'd seriously question any method called `Get...` which has a void return type. And I'm still not clear on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: My get connection method should return an object of Service.The definition should be like : public IOrganizationService GetConnection(bool multi).Now from inside the else loop mentioned below how do i return the service object keeping in mine the thread affinity.Please go thorugh the codes of thearot to have an understanding@Damien_The_Unbeliever

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you want to execute InitializeCRMService in the ThreadPool when a slot is available, and you are executing this only once, the solution depends on what you want to do with the return value of InitializeCRMService.

If you only want to ignore it, I have two options so far.

---

### **Option 1**

```
public void GetConnection(string thread)
{
    //I found that ops is not being used
    //ParallelOptions ops = new ParallelOptions();
    if(thread.Equals("one"))
    {
        Parallel.For(0, 1, i =>
        {
            //You don't really need to have a variable
            /*dynamic serviceObject =*/ InitializeCRMService();
        });
    }
    else if (thread.Equals("multi"))
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem
        (
             new WaitCallback
             (
                 (_) =>
                 {
                      //You don't really need to have a variable
                      /*dynamic serviceObject =*/ InitializeCRMService();
                 }
             )
        );
    }
}
```

On the other hand, if you need to pass it somewhere to store it an reuse it later you can do it like this:

```
public void GetConnection(string thread)
{
    //I found that ops is not being used
    //ParallelOptions ops = new ParallelOptions();

    if(thread.Equals("one"))
    {
        Parallel.For(0, 1, i =>
        {
            //It seems to me a good idea to take the same path here too
            //dynamic serviceObject = InitializeCRMService();
            Store(InitializeCRMService());
        });
    }
    else if (thread.Equals("multi"))
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem
        (
             new WaitCallback
             (
                 (_) =>
                 {
                      Store(InitializeCRMService());
                 }
             )
        );
    }
}
```

---

Where Store would be something like this:

```
private void Store(dynamic serviceObject)
{
    //store serviceObject somewhere you can use it later.
    //Depending on your situation you may want to
    // set a flag or use a ManualResetEvent to notify
    // that serviceObject is ready to be used.
    //Any pre proccess can be done here too.
    //Take care of thread affinity,
    // since this may come from the ThreadPool
    // and the consuming thread may be another one,
    // you may need some synchronization.
}
```

Now, if you need to allow clients of your class to access serviceObject, you can take the following approach:

```
//Note: I marked it as partial because there may be other code not showed here
// in particular I will not write the method GetConnection again. That said...
// you can have it all in a single block in a single file without using partial.
public partial class YourClass
{
    private dynamic _serviceObject;

    private void Store(dynamic serviceObject)
    {
        _serviceObject = serviceObject;
    }

    public dynamic ServiceObject
    {
        get
        {
            return _serviceObject;
        }
    }
}
```

But this doesn't take care of all the cases. In particular if you want to have thread waiting for serviceObject to be ready:

```
public partial class YourClass
{
    private ManualResetEvent _serviceObjectWaitHandle = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private dynamic _serviceObject;


    private void Store(dynamic serviceObject)
    {
        _serviceObject = serviceObject;
        //If you need to do some work as soon as _serviceObject is ready...
        // then it can be done here, this may still be the thread pool thread.
        //If you need to call something like the UI...
        // you will need to use BeginInvoke or a similar solution.
        _serviceObjectWaitHandle.Set();
    }

    public void WaitForServiceObject()
    {
            //You may also expose other overloads, just for convenience.
            //This will wait until Store is executed
            //When _serviceObjectWaitHandle.Set() is called
            // this will let other threads pass.
            _serviceObjectWaitHandle.WaitOne();
    }

    public dynamic ServiceObject
    {
        get
        {
            return _serviceObject;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Still, I haven't covered all the scenarios. For intance... what happens if GetConnection is called multiple times? We need to decide if we want to allow that, and if we do, what do we do with the old serviceObject? (do we need to call something to dismiss it?). This can be problematic, if we allow multiple threads to call GetConnection at once. So by default I will say that we don't, but we don't want to block the other threads either...

The solution? Follows:

```
//This is another part of the same class
//This one includes GetConnection
public partial class YourClass
{
    //1 if GetConnection has been called, 0 otherwise
    private int _initializingServiceObject;

    public void GetConnection(string thread)
    {
        if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _initializingServiceObject, 1, 0) == 0)
        {
            //Go on, it is the first time GetConnection is called

            //I found that ops is not being used
            //ParallelOptions ops = new ParallelOptions();
            if(thread.Equals("one"))
            {
                Parallel.For(0, 1, i =>
                {
                    //It seems to me a good idea to take the same path here too
                    //dynamic serviceObject = InitializeCRMService();
                    Store(InitializeCRMService());
                });
            }
            else if (thread.Equals("multi"))
            {
                ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem
                (
                     new WaitCallback
                     (
                         (_) =>
                         {
                              Store(InitializeCRMService());
                         }
                     )
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

Finally, if we are allowing multiple thread to use _serviceObject, and _serviceObject is not thread safe, we can run into trouble. Using monitor or using a read write lock are two alternatives to solve that.

Do you remember this?

```
    public dynamic ServiceObject
    {
        get
        {
            return _serviceObject;
        }
    }
```

Ok, you want to have the caller access the _serviceObject when it is in a context that will prevent others thread to enter (see System.Threading.Monitor), and make sure it stop using it, and then leave this context I mentioned before.

Now consider that the caller thread could still store a copy of _serviceObject somewhere, and then leave the syncrhonization, and then do something with _serviceObject, and that may happen when another thread is using it.

I'm used to think of every corner case when it comes to threading. But if you have control over the calling threads, you can do it very well with just the property showed above. If you don't... let's talk about it, I warn you, it can be extensive.

---

### **Option 2**

This is a totally different behaviour, the commend [Damien_The_Unbeliever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15498/damien-the-unbeliever) made in your question made me think that you may have intended to return serviceObject. In that case, it is not shared among threads, and it is ok to have multiple serviceObject at a time. And any synchronization needed is left to the caller.

Ok, this may be what you have been looking for:

```
public void GetConnection(string thread, Action<dynamic> callback)
{
    if (ReferenceEquals(callback, null))
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("callback");
    }
    //I found that ops is not being used
    //ParallelOptions ops = new ParallelOptions();
    if(thread.Equals("one"))
    {
        Parallel.For(0, 1, i =>
        {
            callback(InitializeCRMService());
        });
    }
    else if (thread.Equals("multi"))
    {
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem
        (
             new WaitCallback
             (
                 (_) =>
                 {
                      callback(InitializeCRMService());
                 }
             )
        );
    }
}
```

How should the callback look? Well, as soon as it is not shared between threads it is ok. Why? Because each thread that calls GetConnection passes it's own callback Action, and will recieve a different serviceObject, so there is no risk that what one thread does to it affect what the other does to its (since it is not the same serviceObject).

Unless you want to have one thread call this and then shared it with other threads, in which case, it is a problem of the caller and it will be resolved in another place in another moment.

---

One last thing, you could use an enum to represent the options you currently pass in the string thread. In fact, since there are only two options you may consider using a bool, unless they may appear more cases in the future.

Comment: The InitializeCRMServiceMethod has a return type of service object.Will it return the object even if I do not store it in a dynamic object?I really have no idea...My target is when the method is called using multi the code should check for a free thread in the thread pool and utilize it.if it does not find one,it will wait for any of the threads to be free...will this task be accomplished if i use the above code?..Please give me some idea on it..!!!

Comment: @bpc If you are doing nothing with serviceObject, then yes, this code is enough. You could even skip declaring serviceObject. I'll update my answer.

Comment: ok dude..so do you mean that for checking for a free thread in the thread pool and utilizing it will require something extra? I need to check for a free thread in the pool and use it.And suppose it does not find one it will wait for a free one..!!! waiting for your updated answer...

Comment: @bpc I've tested this with some mock I set up. Tell me if it gives you any problems, if I did miss something, or you have any questions about my answer.

Comment: Can you give me some highlight on what I need to do in the store method?I need to pass the _Service object returned by the InitializeCRMService Method.how do i take care of thread affinity and use the manual reset event to notify that the object is ready to be used?

Comment: @bpc expanded my answer. In order to continue expanding it, I may need to know more about how this serviceObject will be used by the callers and if you need to do any execution as soon as serviceObject is available. Yet, I hope what I posted is clear enough.

Comment: @thearot..the clients of my class will call the method like this: GetConnection(string) and they expect back the object of the service.Is it possible for me to declare the return type of the method as Service and get the object from the GetConnection method itself..help needed..:|

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12645/discussion-between-theraot-and-bpc)